# Matlab commands FIR filter

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have this homework where I have a signal, actually a sum of signals and it is requested to make a FIR filter of it which will cut frequencies above 40 Hz and will have width N=41 and for its construction use a squared window. How I am supposed to do that, I have trouble finding the commands, then it says to print with semilogy the transfer function and the impulse response of the filter. Please help me by providing me the necessary commands and the methodology. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Matlab functions that may be useful:

- [`conv`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) for doing the convolution
- [`freqz`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/signal/ref/freqz.html) for plotting frequency response of a discrete-time filter
- [`fir1`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/signal/ref/fir1.html) for designing FIR filters

Note that you have to convert continuous-time frequencies (such as 40 Hz) to discrete-time frequencies, taking into account the sampling rate.